# How to mock $scope.variables in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following test case CompanyCtrlSpec.js

```
describe('ViewCompanyCtrl', function () {
    var $rootScope, scope, $controller , $q ;

   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyApp'));

   beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller ) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function() {
            return $controller('ViewCompanyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            company : {}    
            }); 
        };
    }));

    it('the company type should be equal to an object', function () {
        var controller = new createController();
        //some assertion
    });
});
```

Following is ViewCompanyCtrl.js file

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('ViewCompanyCtrl',
    function ($scope, companyService, $state, meetingService, company, attachmentService) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.company = company;

        $scope.companyInfo = {};
        $scope.companyInfo['AName'] = [$scope.company.Address.Street, $scope.company.Address.ZipCode + ' ' + $scope.company.Address.City].join(', ');
       //more code


    });
```

Following is the app.routes.js file where **company** is getting resolved

```
.state('company', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/company/:companyId',
            resolve: {
                company: function($q, $stateParams, companyService){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    companyService
                        .getCompany($stateParams.companyId)
                        .error(function(data, status, headers){
                            //more code
                        })
                        .success(function(data){
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            },
```

My problem is that i get the following error

```
        TypeError: $scope.company.Address is undefined in C:/Users/MyApp/WebApiRole/app/compan
y/ViewCompanyCtrl.js (line 8)
        @C:/Users/MyApp/WebApiRole/app/company/ViewCompanyCtrl.js:8:42
```

I am guessing that this happens because i didn't mock the **scope.company.Address** in my test case . I am not sure how to do that . Appreciate it if Any one can help me with this , or any method to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the `$scope.company` is the same as the `company` that is injected into your controller.  So you need only to set an `Address` on the `company` that you are injecting into your mock, like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller ) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function() {
        return $controller('ViewCompanyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            company : {
                Address: {/* address data goes here */}
            }
        }); 
    };
}));
```

If you want the company data to be different for each test, simply pass it into your `createController()` function:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller ) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function(company) {
        return $controller('ViewCompanyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            company : company
        }); 
    };
}));

it('the company type should be equal to an object', function () {
    var company = {Address: {/* address data goes here */}};
    var controller = new createController(company);
    //some assertion
});
```

Comment: Thank you !! i kinda knew the idea , but didn't know how to do it since i am new to jasmine . +1 for the explanation too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the controller to the definition of your route. A controller is not a singleton like the other service. It is usually tied to a state or a view.

```
.state('company', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/company/:companyId',
        controller: 'ViewCompanyCtrl'
        resolve: {
            company: function($q, $stateParams, companyService){
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                companyService
                    .getCompany($stateParams.companyId)
                    .error(function(data, status, headers){
                        //more code
                    })
                    .success(function(data){
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
```

Even better I would use the `controller As` convention instead of using scope in your controller. Then your controller will be come the scope.
Aside for that I would highly recommend having a look at [John Papa's coding standard](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) or [Todd Motto's](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide). Both are good and will recommend to use that convention.